# pass into the constructor across an array

Tags: c#, arrays

if i have a class FooWrapper that takes in a Foo during construction:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
FooWrapper fooWrapper = new FooWrapper(foo);
```

Often, i get an array of Foo's back from some API

```
Foo[] foos = _api.GetFoos();
```

is there anyway for me to build up an array of FooWrappers by passing in the appropriate Foo object without simply looping through each one here?

Comment: could you please explain your question a bit more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method.

```
FooWrapper[] wfoos = Array.ConvertAll<Foo, FooWrapper>(foos, delegate(Foo foo){return new FooWrapper(foo);});
```

Comment: You could replace the last delegate parameter with a lambda: 
(f => new FooWrapper(f)). It's a matter of taste.

Comment: The Array.ConvertAll method was introduced in the Framework 2.0 so it should work in V2005. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think arul has a pretty good answer, but I would like to pose the question: is using generics and/or LINQ really 'better' ?

I would use a simple for-loop here. The main reason would be readability.

Comment: i take your point . . . i just was more curious if there was a more suscinct way of doing this in one line of code